about spring-web-5.3.25.jar throw exception java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
i used 【new RestTemplate()】 in my coude to request get/post.
Normally it works correct .
but yesterday , it throw an error :
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52) ~[fssc.boot.jar:?]
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.util.ServiceLoader.parseLine(ServiceLoader.java:255) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(ServiceLoader.java:307) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$200(ServiceLoader.java:185) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:279) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:275) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:251) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:106) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:54) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.java:38) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.<init>(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:64) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:86) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.<init>(RestTemplate.java:167) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]

i want to get the reason, but i failed.
i restart the webservice, and now its normal.
